bpf_probe_read_user() `permission denied: invalid access to map value` in an ebpf program
I have the following structure:
struct ip_event_t {
    __u32 src_ip;
    __u32 dst_ip;
    __u16 src_port;
    __u16 dst_port;
    __u32 payload_length;
    char payload[MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH];
};

And the problematic code:
if (total_len + to_read > MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH) {
    to_read = 0;
    return -1;
}

if (bpf_probe_read_user(&event->payload[total_len], to_read, iov_entry.iov_base) < 0) {
    return -1;
}

It seems the verifier cannot understand the bound check:
; if (total_len + to_read > MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH) {
191: (bf) r8 = r2                     ; frame1: R2_w=2000 R8_w=2000
192: (0f) r8 += r7                    ; frame1: R7=scalar(id=10,smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=1999,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R8_w=scalar(smin=umin=smin32=umin32=2000,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=3999,var_off=(0x0; 0xfff))
; if (total_len + to_read > MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH) {
193: (25) if r8 > 0x7d0 goto pc+88    ; frame1: R8_w=2000
; if (bpf_probe_read_user(&event->payload[total_len], to_read, iov_entry.iov_base) < 0) {
194: (bf) r1 = r6                     ; frame1: R1_w=map_value(map=ip_event_map,ks=4,vs=2016) R6=map_value(map=ip_event_map,ks=4,vs=2016)
195: (0f) r1 += r7                    ; frame1: R1_w=map_value(map=ip_event_map,ks=4,vs=2016,smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=1999,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R7=scalar(id=10,smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=1999,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff))
196: (bf) r3 = r10                    ; frame1: R3_w=fp0 R10=fp0
197: (07) r3 += -56                   ; frame1: R3_w=fp-56
; if (bpf_probe_read_user(&event->payload[total_len], to_read, iov_entry.iov_base) < 0) {
198: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r3 +0)        ; frame1: R3_w=scalar() fp-56=mmmmmmmm
; if (bpf_probe_read_user(&event->payload[total_len], to_read, iov_entry.iov_base) < 0) {
199: (07) r1 += 16                    ; frame1: R1_w=map_value(map=ip_event_map,ks=4,vs=2016,off=16,smin=smin32=0,smax=umax=smax32=umax32=1999,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff))
; if (bpf_probe_read_user(&event->payload[total_len], to_read, iov_entry.iov_base) < 0) {
200: (85) call bpf_probe_read_user#112
invalid access to map value, value_size=2016 off=2015 size=2000
R1 max value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 278 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 2 total_states 21 peak_states 21 mark_read 9
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'bpf_prog_tcp_sendmsg': failed to load: -13

What is the correct way to make the verifier understand the write operation is safe?

It would help if you could share where total_len and to_read are coming from and their respective types.

TL;DR. You're hitting a limitation of the Linux eBPF verifier which can't track relations between variables. One solution may be to replace to_read with a constant.

Verifier Error Explanation

invalid access to map value, value_size=2016 off=2015 size=2000
R1 max value is outside of the allowed memory range


Your program is rejected because the verifier detected that you may read past the map value bounds using bpf_probe_read_user. More specifically, it detected a potential map value access at offset 2015 (total_len's max value + offsetof(ip_event_t, payload)) with access size 2000 (to_read's value). The map value has size 2016 so that would be out-of-bounds.

Why was the bounds check ineffective?
As you noted, the bounds check should have prevented that. However, as we can see in the bytecode returned by the verifier, the bounds check happened on register r8 (instructions 191–193). That register holds the addition of r2 (to_read) and r7 (total_len). The map access via bpf_probe_read_user however didn't use r8, but r2 and r7 directly.
You may be wondering why the verifier can't deduce information on r2 and r7 from the r8 bounds check. It could realize that r8 < Z means r2 + r7 < Z. The verifier unfortunately unable to track such conditions between variables. Tracking relations between variables comes with a high cost, as shown by the Windows eBPF verifier which does support it.

Solution
I noticed that the value of to_read is constant at runtime (according to the verifier). One solution may be to replace the to_read variable with a constant holding value 2000. The compiler would then optimize r2 out of the bytecode and it may be good enough to pass the verifier.
